# How to add a partition boundary only when not exists in SQL Data Warehouse?

Tags: azure-synapse, sql-data-warehouse

I am using Azure SQL Data Warehouse Gen 1, and I create a partition table like this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StatsPerBin1](
[Bin1] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[TimeWindow] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Count] [int] NOT NULL,
[Timestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL)
WITH
(
    DISTRIBUTION = HASH ( [Bin1] ),
    CLUSTERED INDEX([Bin1]),
    PARTITION
    (
        [TimeWindow] RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES ()
     )
)
```

How should I split a partition only when there is no such boundary?

First I think if I can get partition boundaries by table name, then I can write a if statement to determine add partition boundary or not.

But I cannot find a way to associate a table with its corresponding partition values, the partition values of all partitions can be retrieved by

```
SELECT * FROM sys.partition_range_values
```

But it only contains function_id as identifier which I don't know how to join other tables so that I can get partition boundaries by table name.

Comment: Why do you think you need to partition? How many rows are in your table? I'm asking because partitioning, while natural in SQL Server, can be an anti-pattern in ASDW.

Comment: I need to truncate data by month for house keeping, delete record by record is impossible where each month generate 300 million records.

Comment: Depending on what else you are doing in the ELT flow, Lucas, you may find that it is more effective to CTAS the table, excluding the rows to be deleted. That said, 300million/month puts you into the range where Partitioning starts to be a useful technique.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried joining `sys.partition_range_values` with `sys.partition_functions` view?

Granted we cannot create partition functions in *SQL DW*, but the view seems to be still supported.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an out of date question, but I was having the same problem.  Here is a query I ended up with that can get you started.  It is modified slightly from a query for SQL Server documentation:

```
SELECT      s.[name]                        AS      [schema_name]
,           t.[name]                        AS      [table_name]
,           p.[partition_number]            AS      [partition_number]
,           rv.[value]                      AS      [partition_boundary_value]
,           p.[data_compression_desc]       AS      [partition_compression_desc]
FROM        sys.schemas s
JOIN        sys.tables t                    ON      t.[schema_id]         = s.[schema_id]
JOIN        sys.partitions p                ON      p.[object_id]         = t.[object_id]
JOIN        sys.indexes i                   ON      i.[object_id]         = p.[object_id]
                                            AND     i.[index_id]          = p.[index_id]
JOIN        sys.data_spaces ds              ON      ds.[data_space_id]    = i.[data_space_id]
LEFT JOIN   sys.partition_schemes ps        ON      ps.[data_space_id]    = ds.[data_space_id]
LEFT JOIN   sys.partition_functions pf      ON      pf.[function_id]      = ps.[function_id]
LEFT JOIN   sys.partition_range_values rv   ON      rv.[function_id]      = pf.[function_id]
                                            AND     rv.[boundary_id]      = p.[partition_number]
```